# Cannot setup Google Cloud CDN for an external website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-ex-backend-internet-neg and https://medium.com/the-innovation/how-to-enable-google-cdn-for-custom-origin-websites-google-cdn-for-external-websites-56e3fe66cca9 to setup Google Cloud CDN for my website [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org).

For the "Fully qualified domain name and port" in "New network endpoint", I choose [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org).

All others are same as the above two articles, I use HTTP protocol for all the communications. Finally I get a frontend IP address 34.96.69.82. So I try to visit http://34.96.69.82/, but get a default "SORRY" web page instead of the contents from [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org). Why?

Also later I plan to update the DNS A Record for [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org) so that datanumen.org will points to 34.96.69.82 instead of its current IP address. I am just curious that if I do that, then  since what I put in "Fully qualified domain name and port" in "New network endpoint" is [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org), will it cause the following deadloop:

1. a user visit [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org)
2. Based on DNS A record, he will go to 34.96.69.82(frondend)
3. The frontend will request data from backend, and the endpoint is [www.datanumen.org](http://www.datanumen.org),
4. Based on DNS A record, the backend end point will also solved to 34.96.69.82.

Thus will cause a deadloop for ever?

**Update:**

For the 1st question, I find the solution. My website is hosted on a server with shared IP. In article https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-ex-backend-internet-neg, it asks me to add "Host" to the request header, which is used to identify the actual site to be accessed when the request reaches the original server. In my previous configuration, I thought this step is useless so I just skip it. After adding the "Host" field, now I can visit my website properly with the IP address given by Google.

Comment: The frontend and the backend cannot be the same address or alias.

Answer (score 0):

You already fixed your fist issue so you're at a point when you can successfully access your site using an IP address.

**Right now all you need is a [CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview) enabled - if it's not you can do it in the "[backend](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/backends/list)" section of the "load balancing" page.**

Have a look also at [Network Endpoint Groups documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs) to see how to create a load balancer utilising them (the only way you can use GCP's CDN for external site).

To answer your second question - there will be no loop - your site works properly.

Since you're not using secure HTPPS (only HTTP) then you don't have to worry about SSL certificates and the only thing that remains for you to do is to direct your domain to your load-balancer's IP and you're done.

If you encounter any issues or just want to check if CDN is working correctly then have a look at [CDN troubleshooting page](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting-steps).

Most simple way to verify if it's working is to use `curl`: `curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://example.com/style.css` and see if you have `Cache-Control` line present in the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 12:00:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 1977
Cache-Control: max-age=86400,public
Via: 1.1 google
```

However I recommend using HTTPS and SSL certificates for the security reasons - it's much harder to spoof the traffic/listen to the between the site and the client. It's not mandatory though.

Comment: For 2nd question, for the backend, I change the www.datanumen.org to its IP address instead, for fear that may lead to a loop.